# Alert en la misma página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, formularios, alertdialog

Estoy intentando poner un `alert` de *JavaScript* que cuando salte vaya a la misma página que mi `form`, en vez de que que vaya a una página en blanco para mostrarme el error.

Este es el código original:

```
echo "<script>alert('" . $data->__GET('acronimo') . " ya exista en la bbdd');</script>";
```

Y este el que estoy intentando:

```
echo "<script>alert('" . $data->__GET('acronimo') . " ya exista en la bbdd');window.close();</script>";
```

Y ambos, se van siempre a la misma página en blanco en vez de quedarse en la página que está el `form`.

Estuve buscando información pero no di con la tecla. También vi de hacer con *jQuery* los alert que son más vistosos, pero de *jQuery* ando nulo, así que decidí seguir buscando por *JavaScript* a ver si daba con la tecla.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando ahora mismo:

```
public function Registrar(Categoria $data) {
    try {
        $sql = ("INSERT IGNORE INTO categoria (acronimo,categoria,registro_calidad)
VALUES (:acro, :cate, :reca)");
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':acro', $data->__GET('acronimo'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':cate', $data->__GET('categoria'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':reca', $data->__GET('registro_calidad'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo "se insertó ";
        } else {

            echo "<script>alert('" . $data->__GET('acronimo') . " ya existe en la Tabla Categoria');</script>";
        };
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Necesitas abrir un `alert` en la misma ventana del formulario entonces?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas en abrir un alert basta con que hagas lo siguiente.

```js
function message(){
  alert("El dato ya existe en la db");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" OnClick="message()" value="HAZME CLIC" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede que me este equivocando, pero tal como he entendido tu problema es el siguiente:

- Al rellenar un `form` y darle a enviar quieres que si el dato ya existe el error te salte en tu misma pagina y no que te redireccione a otra.

**Explicacion:**

```
<form id="formulario" action="../login/" method="POST">
```

El atributo `action=" "` indica hacia donde se mandaran los datos del formulario, por lo tanto si indica una pagina o un archivo que no existe, este te abrira o una pagina en blanco o te indicara que el recurso no existe.

**Solucion:**

Unas de las formas correctas que hay para hacer lo que tu pides que es mostrar el resultado al mandar el formulario es:

- Utilizar peticion ajax para hacerlo sin refrescar la pagina
- Redireccionar a otra pagina que este a la espera de la respuesta( es decir indicado el atributo `action=" "` y pasandole otro archivo .php que este preparado para mostrar la respuesta
- Poner en `action=" "` a este mismo fichero y prepararlo para recibir la respuesta( Este seria mi recomandacion en este caso para lo que pides).

**Ejemplo:**

```
  <div id="content">
        <form id="formulario" action="../login/" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario">
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Constraseña">
            <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesion">                    
        </form>
    </div>
```

En  este caso en la carpeta `login` tengo un fichero `index.php`

> Nota: Si al redireccionar o escribir una dirección solo se indica la carpeta: `http://localhost/login/` PHP por defecto buscara el fichero `index.php` dentro de dicha carpeta y lo ejecutara, de esta forma evitas tener urls indicando el nombre del fichero como por ejemplo: `http://localhost/login/login.php` o `http://localhost/login.php` y obtienes URLs limpias

Por esta razón lo que indico en el atributo `action=" "` es lo siguiente: sube una posición el el directorio y vuelve a entrar en la carpeta `/login/` y por defecto entra en el fichero index.php en el cual esta el formulario, es decir lo vuelvo a dirigir a si mismo después de mandar el formulario. En tu caso si utilizas como fichero simple es decir lo tienes en `login.php` o en un formato similar indica el atributo de la siguiente forma `action="?"` de esta forma indicas que se lo mande a si mismo.

Después de esto añade en el fichero codigo php:

```
    <?php
    // Si el parametro "user" existe significa que se ha enviado el formulario.
     if(isset($_POST["user"])) { 
         // Codigo cuando se manda el formulario.
         echo "<div>El usuario se ha</div>";

     }
    ?>
```

El `isset()` comprueba si el paramento `user` esta establecido y este solo lo estará cuando venga enviado desde el formulario, ya que al abrirlo por defecto no tendrá asignado nada por lo tanto no entrar en el if.

Todo junto quedaría con una estructura parecida a la siguiente:

```
<?php
        // Si el parametro "user" existe significa que se ha enviado el formulario.
         if(isset($_POST["user"])) {
             $usur = $_POST["user"]; 
             $pass = $_POST["pass"]
             $respuestaLogin = functionLogin($user,$pass);
             if($respuestaLogin=="correcto"){
                header("location:../index/");
                die();
             } else {
                 echo "<div class=\"notificacion error\">Usuario o contraseña incorrectos</div>";
             }

         }
        ?>
        <div id="content">
            <form id="formulario" action="../login/" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario">
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Constraseña">
                <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesion">                    
            </form>
        </div>
```

> solo falta añadir una clase `.notificacion` en el css de esta forma tendra un formato tu notificación del error.
>   En tu caso es exactamente lo mismo lo unico que en vez de `$_POST["user"]` pues supongo que tendras `$_POST["categoria"]` u variables parecidas.

Esta es la forma de mostrar el erro en la misma pagina del formulario sin tener que utilizar AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo de como seria, no va a encontrar la página dado que no he especificado ninguna, pero con que en tu código añadas a la que quieres apuntar sería suficiente

```js
function confirmacion() {
    if (!confirm("ya existe la bbdd")) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="confirmsubmit.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="textboxname"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="return confirmacion();"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Añadi el codigo que estoy utilizando que creo que hubeira estado bien ponerlo antes. Lo que pasa que tu codigo no puedo indexarlo a mi funcion de php (pdo) que estoy utilizando creo yo)